# How to change text in the Alert in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, timer, alert

I want to change the text in the Alert on timer tick, but nothing changes, see example below:

```
private var alert:Alert;
private var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 0);

private function init(){
   timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerTick);
   timer.start();
   alert = Alert.show("Logout in "+ 60 +" seconds","",3);
}       

private function onTimerTick(event:TimerEvent):void{
   alert.text = "Logout in "+(60-timer.currentCount)+" seconds";
}
```

P.S. Title is overridden by this way.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private var uiText:UITextField;

private function init():void{
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerTick);
    timer.start();
    alert = Alert.show("Logout in "+ 60 +" seconds","",3);
    var child:DisplayObjectContainer = alert.getChildAt(0) as DisplayObjectContainer;
    uiText = child.getChildAt(0) as UITextField;
    uiText.text;

}       

private function onTimerTick(event:TimerEvent):void{
    (timer.currentCount > 60) ? [timer.stop(), alert.parent.removeChild(alert)] : void;
    uiText.text = "Logout in "+(60-timer.currentCount).toString()+" seconds";
}
```

Do some thing like this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so this is rather ugly.

```
alert.mx_internal::alertForm.mx_internal::textField.text = "...";
```

Will let you update the text. It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Note that if you're using this approach, you have to import the namespace first prior to accessing it, as follows:

`import mx.core.mx_internal;`